# Should I care about W3C validation?

Tags: angularjs, validation, w3c-validation

I'm learning AngularJS and I found a simple code like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-init="name = 'World'">
    <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

does not pass W3C validation test, mainly because there are non standard attributes (`ng-app`, `ng-init`).

The question is: should I care about W3C validation of my application? Should I abandon AngularJS?

Comment: The best JavaScript framework is *drumroll*: **NONE**! Requires dumping an extra grand total of *zero* bytes and *zero* HTTP requests to the client since it *already* supports (gasp!) JavaScript! Warning: will require you to learn actual standards-compliant JavaScript. One of the most unprofessional things any web/software developer can do is essentially say, "How can we over-complicate our code and weaken it by adding unnecessary dependencies because we didn't bother to learn what we should already know?"

Comment: @John Totally agreed.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use the **data-** html5 attribute which is standard and as far as I know works the same for Angular.
Something like:

```
data-ng-app=""
data-ng-init="xxx"
```

Will work the same in Angular and are validated by W3C.

Look also at this: [ng-app vs. data-ng-app, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference)

Aside from that, from my experience working with standards is always better when your product will be delivered to a possible large crowd (so you'r building a website or a public webapp and so on) with different clients, versions etc.
If you're building a SPA using angular and maybe phonegap to create a mobile app which will be installed on mobile devices as a native app, standard could not be that important, the important thing is that it will work on your target devices.

Answer (score 48):

W3C HTML5 validator maintainer here. We’ve had discussions about how to deal with better facilitating validation of documents that contain custom attributes like Angular’s `ng-*` attributes—attributes which though while non-standard are still very widely and correctly used, and so having the validator emit “error” messages about them isn’t really helping authors.

One feature I’ve added to the HTML5 validator to mitigate this is a “Message filtering” feature that lets you persistently ignore error/warning messages that aren’t important or useful to you. The frontend is here:

http://validator.w3.org/nu/

After you submit a document for checking, on the results page you’ll see a **Message filtering** button, and if you press that, you’ll get a list of all the error messages grouped into sets, with Show/Hide checkboxes.

[image: validator screen shot showing Message Filtering button]

#### Update 2017-02-06: HTML spec proposal for custom attributes

[I added support for custom *elements*](https://github.com/validator/validator/compare/497c81ee62b918a2d6972d290c5805e66078620f...e1285b6b3884ae19826d5d5bf27b72226f87c677) to the [HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (W3C validator)—so, to add support for custom *attributes*, I could use a mechanism similar to what I used for implementing that.

But the HTML checker can’t be changed to allow custom-attribute names until the HTML spec is updated to allow them. For that, [see the proposal in the HTML-spec issue tracker](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2271).

Comment: Very nice! what would be nice too is to have a way to pass filters to vnu.jar https://github.com/validator/validator

Comment: @sideshowbarker any way to get around the 'fatal error: too many messages' (exceeding 1000 `ng-` errors for example)?

Comment: @KevinSylvestre there is no way to override it it you’re using http://validator.w3.org/nu/ but you can if you use the `vnu.jar` file and run it like `java -Dnu.validator.messages.limit=XXXXX ~/vnu.jar some-document-with-a-lot-of-errors.html` (where XXXX is some number). For details about the `vnu.jar` file see https://validator.github.io/validator/ and to download it go to https://github.com/validator/validator/releases/latest.

Comment: Do not, please. The validator is itself a gazillion times more valuable than vue, angular and who knows what kids might come up with next week.
As a side note, I totally agree with Marat-Tanalin about the presumed preference of underscore-/dash-prefixed attributes; it is generic, non-discriminatory and easy to implement.

Comment: what about the latest Angular 4. how do we validate HTML for that because there are new properties such as (click) and [pattern] etc attached to input

Comment: @tanguy_k It's possible now, no matter whether you are using the CLI version or setting up you own `vnu.jar` server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52402947/2261442

Answer (score 5):

Wheter you "should" care or not is up to you. There are many pages out there [which are not valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.google.com&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

HTML5 allows [custom attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) when prefixed with `data-`, so you can use [one of the other equivalent directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) like:

```
<span data-ng-bind="name"></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

> HTML conventions are there to help prevent antipatterns and keep code maintainable.

Yeah. Along those lines, I wrote about that in a little more length recently in a “Why Validate?” section I added to the “About” section of the HTML5 validator:

http://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html#why-validate

The source for the text of that section is here:

https://github.com/validator/validator/blob/master/site/nu-about.html#L160

And pull requests with suggested refinements/additions are welcome.

What I have there currently is this:

> The core reason to run your HTML documents through a conformance
>   checker is simple: To catch unintended mistakes—mistakes you might
>   have otherwise missed—so that you can fix them.
>
> Beyond that, some document-conformance requirements (validity rules)
>   in the HTML spec are there to help you and the users of your documents
>   avoid certain kinds of potential problems. To explain the rationale
>   behind those requirements, the HTML spec contains these two sections:
>
> - [rationale for syntax-level errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#syntax-errors)
> - [rationale for restrictions on content models and on attribute
>     values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values)
>
> To summarize what’s stated in those two sections:
>
> - There are some markup cases defined as errors because they are
>     potential problems for accessibility, usability, interoperability,
>     security, or maintainability—or because they can result in poor
>     performance, or that might cause your scripts to fail in ways that are
>     hard to troubleshoot.
> - Along with those, some markup cases are defined
>     as errors because they can cause you to run into potential problems in
>     HTML parsing and error-handling behavior—so that, say, you’d end up
>     with some unintuitive, unexpected result in the DOM.
>
> Validating your documents alerts you to those potential problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use prefix "data-" in your angular app.
Example:

```
<body data-ng-app data-ng-init="name = 'World'">
   <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: what about in Angular 4? how can the "data-" be added in angular 4

Answer (score 2):

You can use the build system [GulpJs](http://gulpjs.com/) and try a plugin that I wrote that does exactly what you want:

converting `ng-directives` into `data-ng-directives` which is the spec of W3C for html5 validation.

It is heavily tested, and found here: https://github.com/pgilad/gulp-angular-htmlify

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-htmlify

Answer (score 2):

You can `install with npm`:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-angular-htmlify
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the size of your project.

Generally, HTML conventions are there to help prevent antipatterns and keep code maintainable.

That particular rule (requiring a tag to prefixed with -data to be a valid attribute) is in my opinion a little extraneous as it tends to promote extra markup that serves no purpose.

I would say, stick to validating your HTML against WC3 conventions if you are working in a big project with lots of developers. Otherwise, there are no real advantages.

Answer (score -2):

Try running script on secure domail with the https:

Refer the same below using https:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-init="name = 'World'">
    <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```