# Vue js app not passing html validation

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, w3c-validation

I am running my pages through the w3c validation. Vuejs seems to cause some errors due to the @click directives.

```
Warning: Attribute @click is not serializable as XML 1.0.
From line 58, column 1; to line 58, column 24
</div>
<nav @click="toggleNav">
```

Comment: Can you please add little more code for better understanding.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29023301/3806764

Comment: Thats great, I suppose I wished they were not there, that vuejs would render them down in some way. When you actually look at the inspector in chrome they are gone so it must do it after it mounts the app

Comment: The @click is the shorthand version. You can try v-on:click="toggleNav" if that helps you.