# Angular 5 - W3C markup validation

Tags: html, angular, w3c-validation

I'm building Angular 5 application with Angular Universal. Currently I got a problem with W3C validation. The validator is showing errors on every attribute from Angular core.

For example, for code part like:

```html
<span _ngcontent-c1="" class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
```

I'm getting error like:

> Attribute `_ngcontent-c1` not allowed on element `span` at this point.

[image: W3C errors]

I read about adding before Angular attributes `data-` prefix, but on Angular 5 it won't work (I think).

Is there any solution to remove it on server side using Angular Universal, or is there any external tool?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-html5

Comment: You should read a description. I think it won't work with Angular 5. Gr

Comment: Is this W3C validation absolutely required?

Comment: Related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607437/should-i-care-about-w3c-validation/29023301#29023301. What we need is to get agreement on some standard syntax for custom-attribute names. Some proposals have been discussed at https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2271 but there’s been no resolution yet. If/when the HTML spec defines some standard syntax for custom attributes, I could update the W3C HTML checker to recognize them. In the meantime, you can use the message-filtering feature (button) in the checker UI to persistently (using localstorage) filter out those errors

Comment: Okey, thank You for answer. I hope it will be avaible soon.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provide these `_ngcontent-c1`, `_ngcontent-c2` attribute added to specific DOM elements with styles.

`_ngcontent-c1` is used unique identity when rendered from server. when we do `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` and it's the default behaviour of angular.

If you don't want such kind of attribute so you can add `ViewEncapsulation.None` or `ViewEncapsulation.Native`.

eg.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```