# angular 12 Universal, fail html validation with error on app selector

Tags: html, angular, angular-universal

Any ideas what to do, whit this error?

The simple test as angular v12, Universal SSR fail the W3 HTML validation.

the AppComponent have a selector like:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and on index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <app id="app"></app>
</body>
</html>
```

But W3 HTML validation shows an error:

[image]

I also try to change the selector name to like: 'project' and I got the same error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: Use a name with a dash in it, such as `app-root`

Weirdly, the validator will not complain about app-root or other angular directive tags, but will complain for all `_ngcontent-**` attribute.

Note that there is a message filtering feature in the w3c validator so that you can ignore specific warnings (like the `ngcontent` attribute) (message from w3c maintainer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29023301/1160794))

Comment: seem's it doesn't matter to what name I change or add to the selector in angular. The error will continue to show up

Comment: Change to a name with a dash in it: `app-root`

Comment: @David nice explanation and lovely answear :)