# Attribute ng-view not allowed on element div at this point

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, w3c, w3c-validation

I've been receiving this error using validator.w3.org as HTML5

"Attribute ng-view not allowed on element div at this point"

how can I  solve this problem passing a ng-view through a div ?

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: What do you need and why?

Comment: What does that even mean? please put a little more effort into asking questions that completely explain your issues

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention the validator.. how can I fix that error when I pass my website in validator.w3.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [w3c validation with Directives in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949926/w3c-validation-with-directives-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 16):

It is specified somewhere on AngularJS Site that if you want a valid html you should place `data-` before every `ng-something`. For you

```
<div data-ng-view></div>
```

will make the example valid.

Hope it helps. +1 answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, does it really matter for e.g. SEO purposes to prefix everything non-standard with "data-"? Or it really doesn't matter, and is just a waste of time?

Comment: As far as I know, it is a waste of time but you should be consistent. Either use data- everwhere or don't (in each website).